# Searching for data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Please take a look at the following table:

[image: MySQL Table with results]

I am building a search engine which returns `card_id` values, based on search of `category_id` and `value_id` values.

To better explain the search mechanism, imagine that we are trying to find a car (`card_id`) by supplying information what part (`value_id`) the car should has in every category (`category_id`).

In example, we may want to find a car (`card_id`), where category "Fuel Type" (`category_id`) has a value "Diesel" (`value_id`), and category "Gearbox" (`category_id`) has a  value "Manual" (`value_id`).

My problem is that my knowledge is not sufficient to build a query, which will returns `card_id`s which contains more than one pair of `category_id` and `value_id`.

For example, if I want to search a car with diesel engine, I could build a query like this:

`SELECT card_id FROM cars WHERE category_id=1 AND value_id=2`

where `category_id = 1` is a category "Fuel Type" and `value_id = 2` is "Diesel".

My question is, how can I build a query, which will look for more category-value pairs? For example, I want to look for diesel cars with manual gearbox.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT card_id
FROM cars
GROUP BY card_id
HAVING SUM(category_id = 1 AND value_id = 2) > 0 AND
       SUM(category_id = 3 and value_id = 43) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that match a given condition.  You can add as many conditions as you like.  The first, for instance, says that there is at least one row where the category is 1 and the value is 2.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d9fe/1/0)

Comment: Your solution works as expected. Thank you for the code and the explanation, and for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to create a user defined function that takes a table of attribute/value pairs and returns a table of matching cars. This has the advantage of allowing an arbitrary number of attribute/value pairs without resorting to dynamic SQL.

```
--Declare a "sample" table for proof of concept, replace this with your real data table
DECLARE @T TABLE(PID int, Attr Int, Val int)
--Populate the data table
INSERT INTO @T(PID , Attr , Val) VALUES (1,1,1), (1,3,5),(1,7,9),(2,1,2),(2,3,5),(2,7,9),(3,1,1),(3,3,5), (3,7,9)

--Declare this as a User Defined Table Type, the function would take this as an input
DECLARE @C TABLE(Attr Int, Val int)
--This would be populated by the code that calls the function
INSERT INTO @C (Attr , Val) VALUES (1,1),(7,9)

--The function (or stored procedure) body begins here
--Get a list of IDs for which there is not a requested attribute that doesn't have a matching value for that ID
SELECT DISTINCT PID 
FROM @T as T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT C.ATTR FROM @C as C 
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @T as I 
                                    WHERE I.Attr = C.Attr and I.Val = C.Val and I.PID = T.PID ))
```